# How to configure Jenkinsfile so that an aborted/timed out stage ends pipeline and marks build as pass?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

My Jenkinsfile is defined such that I have the following pipeline stages:

```
checkout--setup--tests--deploy--post deploy stuff
```

My deploy stage is based on user input (Click 'deploy' button to deploy, abort to not) and it has a timeout incase a user does not take any action within the time period.

Currently if the deploy stage times out or a user clicks abort the pipeline still moves on to the next stage.

Is there a way to configure the Jenkinsfile such that it can only move on to the next stage if and only if I've clicked deploy and the deploy stage is complete?

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional statement on the `input` return value and then just set `currentBuild.result` to [whatever you want](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/6a4d800091926c5484483f79e8936ac9d21d67a1/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Result.java#L57-L80) and `return`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scenario where I want to ignore some errors and keep going. To do that, I put a try block around the problem bit and do the next bit in a finally block. For your scenario put a try/finally block around the whole pipeline and do just do nothing in the finally block.